# What string methods would I need to make it look Javaish?

Tags: java, string

I'm a C programmer and not Java programmer. I don't know what methods are available in Java and what not. I've been struggling with this for hours.

Its part of a big program. I've a string, I need what vowels, consonants & numbers are present in the string.

```
string s = "asdf";
char[] charArr = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if( charArr[i] == 'a' || charArr[i] == 'e' || charArr[i] == 'i' || charArr[i] == 'o' || charArr[i] == 'u')
            {
                // stuff here           
            }
        }
```

But this doesn't look like Java code. I'm still thinking in terms of C. I want to make it look like Java. Are there any methods for I can use?

Comment: Start with the documentation. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: Yes! I've been using the same docs. This is where I got methods for converting it into char array etc. But doesn't this converting to char and iterating & then checking if each char is a vowel, look like C? Would you do the same in java?

Comment: There are number of helper functions in the String class for this ... but it depends on what you intend to do with them ... do you need the indexes of all occurrences? You just wanting to count the number of occurrences for each category?

Comment: I think it is a _Javaish_ as it can be!

Comment: @Matthew Cox: indexes of all occurances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possibility, which is quite readable... :-)

At least, for readability, you should extract the if-test as methods like isVowel, isConsonant.

```
public class TestStringIteration {

    private static final HashSet<Character> VOWELS = new HashSet<Character>(
            Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
    private static final HashSet<Character> CONSONANTS = new HashSet<Character>(
            Arrays.asList('b', 'c')); // Add more letters :-)

    void stringTest(String s) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                // This is a digit
            } else if (isVowel(c)) {
                // This is a vowel
            } else if(isConsonant(c)) {
                // This is a consonant
            }
        }
    }


    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return VOWELS.contains(c);
    }

    private static boolean isConsonant(char c) {
        return CONSONANTS.contains(c);
    }
}
```

EDIT: made `isVowel` and `isConsonant` static

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, there's nothing wrong with your approach. No matter what you have to iterate over all the characters. You  might want to use an enhanced for loop if you don't care about the index value.

```
for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
    if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || ...){
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: toCharArray() is unnecessary there, the extended for loop will work just as well with a string. There are only few reasons in Java to ever manipulate a char array directly.

Comment: @Voo: A String is neither an array or Iterable.

Comment: You can't? Sorry, too much Python it seems - I was sure that was possible xX

Comment: Yeah, I think they should extend the for-loop to work with `CharSequence` too.

Answer (score 2):

In this case Java code would not be very different from C

```
private enum CharType {VOWEL, CONSONANT, NUMBER, OTHER;}

static CharType getType(final char ch) {

if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
switch (ch) {
case 'a': case 'A':
case 'e': case 'E':
case 'i': case 'I':
case 'o': case 'O':
case 'u': case 'U':
  return CharType.VOWEL;
default:
  return CharType.CONSONANT;
}
} else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') { 
  return CharType.NUMBER;
}

  return CharType.OTHER;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As *Javaish* as [possible](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5003547) ;-)

```
String s = "asdf".toLowerCase();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if(c ==  'a' || c ==  'e' || c ==  'i' || c ==  'o' || c ==  'u')
    {
            // stuff here           
    }
}
```

Are you rewritting C code to Java?

Comment: (You've missed out the `toLowerCase` part.) @claws: There's anything wrong with your version, but this is what you asked for. :-) And if you're using a modern JVM, don't worry about the fact it looks like a lot of function calls. The JIT will handle it, and you get the bonus that you're not using duplicate memory for the `char[]`.

Comment: You should not call `charAt(i)` 5 times in the same condition, only once and put the result in an variable.

Comment: I guess it doesn't hurt performance much to use `chartAt()` multiple times but the overall readability with extracted variable is much better, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of pointers (no pun intended :D) claws.
Usually in Java we tend to work with `String`s and not with `char[]`, we widely use the methods available in the [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class. There are other useful methods in utility classes such as Apache Commons Lang lib http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no reason to use a normal for loop for that kind of problem:

```
String s = "asdf";
for(char c : s.toLowerCase()) {
    if( c ==  'a' || c ==  'e' || c ==  'i' || c ==  'o' || c ==  'u') {
            // stuff here           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what makes you think your code isn't java? it is, and would be more efficient than using `String.charAt` repeatedly. converting the string to a `char[]` is a good idea if you are going to access characters at random positions, provided the string isn't too long.

if you're going to access individual characters in sequence however there are better solutions, such as [`StringReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html).

i would also suggest splitting your logic out a little though. make an `isVowel(char c)` method for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Java API to make it look more javaish you can try an approach with regular expressions:

```
String input = "foo bar fun for vowels";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aAeEiIoOuU]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while ( m.find() ) {
    // stuff here with my example output
    System.out.println("Index: " + m.start() + " vowel was: " + input.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
```

But there is nothing wrong with your code. And yours is more performant than mine. It's just for the looks.